# Нет ли двусмысленности в следующей фразе?

Tags: смысл

На одном из сайтов проводится голосование по сериалам/фильмам по швейцарской системе. Претенденты разбиты на пары, и из каждой пары надо выбрать один сериал/фильм. Имеется условие, о котором хочу спросить, что оно означает.

**"Если вы не смотрели хотя бы один из вариантов, то мы рекомендуем вам воздержаться от голосования по данной паре."**

Как правильно трактовать эту фразу, нет ли здесь двусмысленности?

Я не могу голосовать, если смотрел только один вариант, или же я могу голосовать, если смотрел "хотя бы один вариант", т.к. "хотя бы один вариант" я всё же смотрел?

Answer (score 2):

*Если вы не смотрели хотя бы один из вариантов, то мы рекомендуем вам воздержаться от голосования по данной паре.*

Имеется в виду следующее. Если Вы посмотрели оба фильма, Вы можете голосовать. В противном случае Вам рекомендуют воздержаться от голосования. То есть если Вы посмотрели только один или ни одного, то лучше не голосовать.

Пояснение: высказывание "не смотрел хотя бы один из двух" является логическим отрицанием высказывания "смотрел оба".

Comment: *высказывание "не смотрел хотя бы один из двух" является логическим отрицанием высказывания "смотрел оба".* - а вот это совсем не очевидно без контекста. Язык - не математическая логика, тут все не так формализовано. См. пример в моем ответе.

Comment: @Мимоходов Вы правы, спасибо за интересный пример.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет двусмысленности, есть ошибка в формулировке (стилистическая).
Слово "вариант" надо заменить на что-то более "смотрибельное":

"Если вы не смотрели ***хотя бы один из фильмов*** пары, то мы рекомендуем вам воздержаться от голосования по данной паре."

Теперь попробую подробно. На самом деле все не так просто.

> Как правильно трактовать эту фразу, нет ли здесь двусмысленности?
>
> Я не могу голосовать, если смотрел только один вариант, или же я могу
>   голосовать, если смотрел "хотя бы один вариант", т.к. "хотя бы один
>   вариант" я всё же смотрел?

Здесь нет двусмысленности только потому, что контекст однозначный. Чтобы голосовать ответственно, надо посмотреть оба. Но сама грамматика фразы не делает семантику однозначной. 
Стоит поставить другой контекст - и все будет совершенно иначе смотреться.

*Чтобы стать аудитором, надо иметь бухгалтерское или юридическое образование. Если вы не имеете хотя бы одного из них, то вы не можете претендовать на получение аудиторского диплома.*

И кто тут будет утверждать, что надо иметь **оба** образования? А ведь построение фразы точно такое же. Впрочем, во избежание подобных недоразумений юристы обычно в своих текстах избегают подобных "контекстно-зависимых" формулировок. В юридическом стиле исходная фразе в зависимости от смысла звучала бы так.

*"Если вы не смотрели один или оба из фильмов пары, то мы рекомендуем вам воздержаться от голосования по данной паре."*

или

*"Если вы не смотрели ни один из фильмов пары, то мы рекомендуем вам воздержаться от голосования по данной паре."*

Здесь вероятность неправильного понимания сведена если не к нулю, то к минимуму.

Comment: "Язык - не математическая логика". Должен согласиться

Comment: Формально "не иметь хотя бы один из двух" можно понимать двояко": (1) отрицание к "иметь хотя бы один из двух", то есть состояние "не иметь ни одного"; (2) состояние  "не иметь" по отношению к хотя бы одному из двух, то есть "отсутствие хотя бы одного".

Answer (score 0):

Никакой двусмысленности, все однозначно - если хотя бы один из двух фильмов вы не смотрели, то просят не голосовать.

Answer (score -2):

*Если вы не смотрели хотя бы один из вариантов, то мы рекомендуем вам воздержаться от голосования по данной паре.*

Здесь двойное отрицание: ***не смотрели*** и ***воздержаться от голосования***, что равно ***не голосовать***. Т.е. вас просят (не запрещают) не голосовать, если не видели ни одного фильма (хотя бы одного) из предложенных двух. Или предлагают **голосовать**, если вы **смотрели** только один из этой пары. Это разумно, не находите?